# Sending packets in a Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, sip

I've written a simple java applet that sends SIP packets to our server.  When running within eclipse in the Sun applet viewer, everything works perfectly, but when I attempt to embed the applet in a web browser (using applet tags), the applet successfully runs, but no packets are being sent.  I verified this using wireshark.  Are there some kind of security settings in IE/chrome that I am not aware of?  I guess I can show code if necessary.  Thanks

Comment: Are yoo sending to the server where the applet came from? If not, you need to sign the applet.

Comment: *"simple java applet"* Contradiction in terms.  Applets are *never* simple when it comes time to deploy.  *"Are there some kind of security settings.."*  **Yes.**

Comment: BTW 1) What is the output in the Java Console?  2) Why is this an applet in any case?  The fact you were running it in Eclipse/appletviewer suggests it does not rely heavily on JavaScript (if at all), and would likely be better received as a free floating app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  But sort the security problems first, the same security environment applies to both applets and JWS apps.

Comment: I am not sending to the server from where the applet came from so I guess I will have to sign it.  Why must it be an applet? Long story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think applets can communicate only with the source server, similar to javascript ajax calls, if it wasnt that way, then you could make some kind of attack with a simple servlet in a popular site.

Check that you're reaching the source server.

Cheers!

Comment: You are right not to be sure, it isn't constrained to SSL only. Not sure why you even mentioned that really.

Comment: I thought I have read it somewhere, NVM, thanks for the input!

Comment: If I can figure out how to sign the app, then can I communicate with different servers?

Comment: I don't think any certificate will do, I think you need a proper certificate from a certification authority to sign your applet.

Comment: I signed the app but I'm still getting the same problem.  Starting to think that an applet may not be the best solution for this problem